# Stuggling to Create GitLab-CI Pipeline that includes 'schedules' and 'changes' declarations

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline, katalon-studio

I have a GitLab-CI pipeline in place with my Katalon Studio automation tests that I would like to have the following functionality:

1. Various nightly schedules that run based on scheduled variables being present.
2. Changes declaration so pushes to the repo only trigger a pipeline run if certain files have been touched.

I have the scheduled portion running as expected, but I am struggling on pairing that with the 'changes' declaration to only run the pipeline IF someone pushes after changing certain files.  Can someone help? I am guessing this is an issue with my YAML formatting.

Here is an example snippet from my current GitLab-CI.yaml

```
Example Tests: 
 stage: Example
 tags:
    - aws-medium-runner
 script:
   - MY_SCRIPT
 rules:
  - if: $SCHEDULE_A == "true" # tied to schedule A in scheduler tool
    when: always
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"' 
    changes: # Only run on pushes if changes have been made to certain directories
    - Test\ Cases/Example/*
    - Object\ Repository/Example/*
    - Test\ Suites/Example/*
    - Scripts/Example/*
    when: always
 dependencies:
   - Set Release Version
```

Comment: What is not working as expected? I don't think you need to escape spaces in paths with a backslash -- that may be your problem. Your last `changes:` rule for `Scripts/Example/*` looks fine, for example. Does that  one work as expected?

Comment: I have tried both with and without the escaping character in the file paths.  Right now, when I push to my repo, all of my pipeline stages are running regardless of if a file within that `changes:` rule was impacted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 spaces on the `changes:` part.
It should work when you add those. (see the example below)

And in case you want to combine the 2 rules with the same conditions, you can combine them into one rule:

```yaml
Example Tests: 
 stage: Example
 tags:
    - aws-medium-runner
 script:
   - MY_SCRIPT
 rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" || $SCHEDULE_A == "true"' 
    changes: # Only run on pushes if changes have been made to certain directories
      - Test Cases/Example/*
      - Object Repository/Example/*
      - Test Suites/Example/*
      - Scripts/Example/*
    when: always
 dependencies:
   - Set Release Version
```

Comment: I took your suggestion to combine my rules and added spaces to the `changes:` section.  After this update, my scheduled pipelines are working as expected.  However, anytime a push is made to my repository, Example stage is not triggered, even if files defined in the changes section were updated.  Any ideas?